# Group a data in Unix shell or Group by in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

What is the best and the most optimized way to group by data on multiple columns ?

The data on which the operation need to be performed is 400 x 10 million row or line .
I have multiplied with ten because we have 10 partitions or 10 files each with approx 400 M rows

Problem :
After fetching the columns from oracle (10  columns) in a temp Table
or in a temp file by spooling it.On the fetched data I need to group by some columns and add  (summation) some columns.

Option :

1. I can do it by the Query using group by clause in the same query rather
   than creating a temp table. : Down side I get Reference snapshot too
   old.
2. I get the data in a temp table, and make sure the table partitioning
   is such that the group by becomes fast.
3. I get the data in a file and do a grouping of data using awk or
   unix/perl command.

Query :

```
select /*+ parallel (a,10) */
  customer_type, customer_sub_type, charge_code, cycle,month,
  sum(amount),sum(final_amount)
from htg_customer_data a
where cycle=1
and month=1
and sys_creation_date < to_date('20140131235959', yyyymmddhh24miss)
group by customer_type, customer_sub_type, charge_code, cycle, month
```

Table is partitioned on cycle and month , and it has 10 partitions. 400 Million rows into each . None of the above used fields have index. The index column is not required into the extract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't give a whole lot of information to go on.

In general, doing operations in the database will be faster than moving the data to another environment.  There are several reasons for this:

- The database server is typically more powerful than the application server.
- The database engine can take advantage of grid computing (multiple processors, multiple disks)
- The database engine can optimize the query "intelligently"
- The database engine can implement better techniques than "sort-and-loop" for aggregation

All of these apply to Oracle, which has sophisticated algorithms and a good optimizer.

I would immediately rule out (3) because just moving such a large quantity of data out of the database is going to be a long process.  Then you have to deal with a very large file to do what you really want to do.

In all likelihood, (1) is the best approach.  There may be some circumstances where temporary tables could provide an additional performance boost.

Comment: Please let me know what kind of info you are looking for ? Is it regarding the hardware configuration and oracle version .

Comment: @Kimi . . . What is the query that you are considering in the database?  What is the table structure, including indexes and partitioning?

Comment: @Kimi . . . The aggregation in the database should be fine.  Oracle *should* be smart enough to do it separately for each partition, because the partitioning keys are in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Using /*+ MATERIALIZE */ will it help to fasten the above a query ?

Comment: @Kimi . . . You query has not subqueries so I don't see how that hint is relevant.